# Why it is called "BatchNorm" not "Batch Standardize"?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, normalization, standardization, batch-normalization

Regarding the differences between "Normalization" and "Standardization," I found that:

> Normalization: Is the process of making a dataset having a specified range, probably [0,1] following this equation:
> $$ x = {x - \min(x) \over \max(x)-\min(x)} $$

> Standardization: Refers to making the dataset/ layer have Zero-mean and Unit-variance
> $$ x = {x - \mu_x \over \sigma_x} $$

However, during BatchNorm, we do standardization not Normalization. Am I correct?

Comment: Welcome to the "naming" problem. Arguably the hardest problem in the sciences (also in programming). People choose a name (or notation) they think sounds "cool" or "fine" to allow them to get a paper out quickly, without too much thought if its semantics are adequately captured by that name (if at all possible). Then people start using it, and that's that. That's how we end up with terms like "ChatGPT hallucinates" instead of "confabulates", for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those names are not standardized (pun intended), "normalization", "standardization", and "scaling" are often used interchangeably for different transformations.

See for example [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) or [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) that says

> This process of converting a raw score into a standard score is called **standardizing** or **normalizing** (however, "normalizing" can refer to many types of ratios; see normalization for more).